# How to plot sub-region of the 2-unit simplex in Matlab

Tags: matlab, 3d, matlab-figure

I have a Matlab array `R` of size `3x500` (see below). Each column of `R`, `R(:,i)`, represents a point defined by the coordinates `x=Rb(1,i)`,`y=Rb(2,i)`, `z=Rb(3,i)`. Each of such points is such that `x>=0`, `y>=0`, `z>=0` and `x+y+z=1`. I.e., each of such points belongs to the 2-unit simplex.

Let `A` be the surface obtained by connecting the points in `R`.

I would like to create a 3 dimensional Matlab figure in which we can see

1) the 2-unit simplex

2) the surface `A` inside the  2-unit simplex.

In other words, I would like to obtained  figure like below, where the shaded area is the 2-unit simplex and the dark area is (for example) `A`.

[image: image 2]

I have tried this (just for `A`):

```matlab
T = delaunayTriangulation(R');
A = convexHull(T);
patch('Faces',A,'Vertices',T.Points,'FaceColor','g');
view(3);
```

This is what I get:

[image: This]

It does not look similar to my hand drawn figure. I guess it is a matter of axis positions, rotations, etc. Furthermore, I don't know how to plot also the 2-unit simplex. Could you help?

**Data**:

```
R=[0.753708492898639,0.934231100681919,0.753690044440217,0.934233754652432,0.752996350233537,0.934210408157169,0.753692038254741,0.934193272087065,0.934365583215163,0.750445998275021,0.753068853721270,0.934233781548450,0.934363620468395,0.934387397472382,0.750455043996538,0.748053533120517,0.753692710133161,0.934233556099641,0.747956110621742,0.753074378940705,0.753690439972500,0.937678075138566,0.937678086970556,0.934338198779680,0.935186140953276,0.747830580490062,0.748134159068826,0.934365562846216,0.937678384189489,0.747955800916425,0.748134015402597,0.753691584057228,0.934210451029704,0.937724734085845,0.747816335733460,0.747775614056854,0.938579429584247,0.737486403124538,0.934231361599596,0.934233731737328,0.750462822060003,0.753653470923750,0.938215551600985,0.939001216063012,0.937675453135004,0.937731124438633,0.747830193759773,0.737480387364348,0.934599986759564,0.747830540722560,0.747956142247373,0.939001527193106,0.737486823813907,0.753692645275417,0.934233545852018,0.937868708409900,0.737402806350975,0.753070298576638,0.734881143694388,0.939001272857268,0.939262531674500,0.737403759836701,0.939185323467773,0.934166473717580,0.937867015720382,0.734877525921658,0.934365500775319,0.747823231533936,0.748135597443358,0.937724734900515,0.939264636282912,0.939262867689582,0.734685755167658,0.734726460879251,0.737486772460080,0.747830507663689,0.937538624922944,0.737402864101458,0.934185598453479,0.753691645762843,0.939003222597406,0.939263620446645,0.939396859586687,0.399502379996283,0.934233741035278,0.939001320921050,0.750456594940521,0.939399241286841,0.399502421606493,0.939399257312196,0.939176005485126,0.737485869599931,0.734723791382523,0.747957725133385,0.939394207465425,0.399502321806616,0.934583934646736,0.399499329722915,0.937868708065697,0.939396274848374,0.939394677058129,0.737480711740311,0.737376084116527,0.399281520577946,0.737541437337530,0.939264648534226,0.399500627978265,0.753692136723135,0.939399254492048,0.934233581086002,0.937724414380014,0.750463159944483,0.734268388431703,0.939262484123414,0.399281148727835,0.939396286213951,0.748054232475701,0.939394783741107,0.478564641105421,0.399343655628326,0.934365226257003,0.939341652953018,0.939003195147427,0.939396298436251,0.391548229456114,0.399499924718335,0.399404889289515,0.939341737919031,0.937538595856592,0.747818285759773,0.394124697842663,0.734877772450041,0.939001227154722,0.939398427094521,0.939396168973249,0.737415814595204,0.399264421486102,0.399745110658153,0.934185584702680,0.939399256453765,0.753659717575284,0.939342827518712,0.939396294978879,0.399404831109202,0.748135696329336,0.937868692770249,0.399265324535779,0.399499939697158,0.934233698491139,0.939264648995575,0.478601392937535,0.395175600042841,0.939396169061680,0.747832218046950,0.399266915973986,0.478796777180429,0.939342740186131,0.934600000546560,0.391811860276028,0.734876657815101,0.939263592992276,0.399499205478467,0.399277087295012,0.939396166471084,0.937724699813415,0.737488247305107,0.939396291390713,0.391546604836326,0.939302561710010,0.399506758749660,0.939003259202258,0.939396292007131,0.753692718380428,0.939344588587619,0.750462662616844,0.391561141051592,0.399499680837291,0.939398423178239,0.747957099278981,0.939341722568516,0.734877043744686,0.399277119190108,0.400600442574033,0.934233710201019,0.394124592922733,0.478662698594133,0.939396176476023,0.399404832150885,0.939399254937624,0.395175649507640,0.939394533731957,0.394124668368213,0.737488244314263,0.934413280074065,0.939001317041725,0.391820831322397,0.939344519065756,0.937724736451735,0.478667552127510,0.399506297640867,0.939371439727857,0.399277153162000,0.399265313663829,0.939396290923179,0.391546879947646,0.753691559132219,0.939395052704930,0.399499271498297,0.737052809036231,0.748053960270007,0.478795546466524,0.939263611924574,0.939396294562356,0.939344593389436,0.391546596625418,0.478600992207943,0.399343674066044,0.934210369108547,0.737516203071356,0.939396292381380,0.479232601813347,0.399744486966678,0.391547858210264,0.939396177660451,0.399265296780274,0.400594448455606,0.399277137996974,0.478602139206519,0.934365557859874,0.395175610341690,0.937724377101970,0.939396298750829,0.939001345192864,0.394109497476714,0.939344605229984,0.737403752674821,0.392434914737529,0.939344506403962,0.748137372432063,0.399499350444488,0.399265276760069,0.394124651989185,0.478667370472509,0.939396176920344,0.939399252247116,0.939264471185674,0.391819989464985,0.939344606493525,0.399311231304071,0.753692296494357,0.747832075467758,0.939395910368460,0.399748748072768,0.478668626474642,0.939340189457372,0.478602675213044,0.391548021757086,0.399277055027441,0.937677811968570,0.939396031615193,0.934233500745540,0.478797204356085,0.939394258073755,0.737401710837347,0.391546587036156,0.399499221485779,0.939002871800707,0.395176750174514,0.400596362783436,0.478603233661974,0.399265252386327,0.939344265657490,0.939396031576483,0.394117012521967,0.391547770439989,0.394124646882589,0.748055005064550,0.478827160527191,0.395149429854861,0.399750257093843,0.939396935299565,0.939396018268785,0.939394796251723,0.399281258140344,0.478668260230610,0.939344325747572,0.391821203789699,0.753691546965636,0.939395892712684,0.399266804028463,0.935185937184763,0.737484187469316,0.478668649461763,0.399499193728771,0.478602533162827,0.939340176602781,0.391548208115317,0.400581185884024,0.939001011852914,0.939395905552974,0.399265242072001,0.939344330902810,0.478668645926087,0.391546491292784,0.734225655377966,0.399280694238324,0.391546741979845,0.394124048302531,0.939396021953752,0.478603084048232,0.939398993828620,0.395176759662948,0.934233493102576,0.939340234666267,0.391547871689911,0.939396031445096,0.747832035845850,0.478797979059573,0.939344333824532,0.400602203757056,0.399500688281153,0.395149508482347,0.399265229208068,0.478663861996979,0.391894369988426,0.939340209686367,0.939344284644088,0.938220237114615,0.734677443574538,0.394124580423301,0.478668388770976,0.750467569237764,0.478826977308991,0.399278156095516,0.391819932137318,0.478602660272237,0.939394783475857,0.400595307270556,0.939398987271045,0.391546811444508,0.394116998145007,0.478668680835911,0.939344265730142,0.391546510573614,0.399500662052549,0.391547624900765,0.939395879775017,0.939396027642365,0.399265224739078,0.395176756155721,0.478602808299318,0.939395901352442,0.935185890432499,0.479230466725647,0.737374000384403,0.478668805952774,0.939344277165948,0.399278255732943,0.395150351735890,0.400601519442795,0.394124551662990,0.478603224370416,0.392436643076444,0.939344336035652,0.939340152768135,0.939398151689399,0.399345112395488,0.391560494791884,0.391820072495251,0.478668394248415,0.399264347185239,0.747953835176229,0.391546907391820,0.391546700189696,0.478668857335283,0.391546509677123,0.939344335560001,0.478601991908679,0.400595611470896,0.939395903859570,0.478668795896609,0.939340194504353,0.399266620097893,0.939344332499528,0.939394261586017,0.394109305612469,0.395176786470344,0.939391937352441,0.399278552179867,0.478602799452623,0.939340201957267,0.478795461652589,0.395176739467573,0.394125064658685,0.400602174525852,0.395146444452813,0.391546720165302,0.478668796264896,0.478603247913660,0.939340197695874,0.391820719203826,0.939340205715339,0.391546525174132,0.391546817238550,0.478797959073873,0.391819949229497,0.478668310442996,0.394118342413360,0.395116240858227,0.478822631186990,0.391547629123766,0.939340197074529,0.400595402369550,0.939340192494122,0.478602097629803,0.391549031167793,0.939340195016375,0.478668781180965,0.395176787205898,0.391548480189936,0.478668687881036,0.391546490017868,0.478602807774384,0.478822620482479,0.395176632574231,0.395148558970907,0.478668494781798,0.478668785233278,0.391819982594828,0.400601660595708,0.391546869610338,0.478603271118297,0.391546492359825,0.391816392600849,0.478798054495106,0.478668854290695,0.478668817808356,0.395113412430419,0.400598327829976,0.391817589972338,0.478668901895024,0.478795494248995,0.400595512341493,0.478601986960850,0.478668555827983,0.391811703357209,0.395149824006260,0.395178546018643,0.395175540244346,0.478668874812437,0.478602795749428,0.478603269319701,0.478602851694062,0.391820026431297,0.395113409806388,0.478668538141876,0.391893825991538,0.400601707533504,0.391893229760560,0.478668829995560,0.478664443728275,0.478668535732658,0.478668456235306,0.395176711223198,0.400596324964821,0.395176743550020,0.400595531872106,0.478602653760929,0.478603378391092,0.395113457993132,0.478602745232365,0.395176784889396,0.478668516210419,0.395150352664134,0.478602778297649,0.395148467035391,0.478663372779565,0.400602239086030,0.478663999367012,0.395176938455116,0.478603362860210,0.400596237111868,0.395175590879203,0.478602953309844,0.478602171501905,0.400595664211248,0.395175529817359,0.478603369714886,0.395176736267297,0.478603237475346,0.478602652282632,0.400596052578329,0.478602927584462,0.400601775298214,0.400594283704823,0.478602665703473,0.400594300614006,0.478602912076685,0.478602493016141,0.400611696592847;0.206029989375089,0.0255042878222986,0.206048557556012,0.0255013197655500,0.206599873448513,0.0255271961959456,0.206046389139454,0.0255442556799553,0.0253234558997147,0.208530975510884,0.206544195312660,0.0255017341616576,0.0253260814571950,0.0252912512266648,0.208524852476630,0.210120148789422,0.206045935097880,0.0255018452337725,0.210174823620863,0.206539630596669,0.206048075089408,0.0195772995730938,0.0195774410252597,0.0253609307397613,0.0240119540462720,0.210238954998185,0.210072956785726,0.0253239977268070,0.0195756203107723,0.210174966179418,0.210073069238035,0.206047011255575,0.0255270964190429,0.0194817336786999,0.210244932646927,0.210261990817961,0.0172259829590110,0.214335093230822,0.0255040906769458,0.0255018083003497,0.208519041495165,0.206078368770452,0.0182437924293794,0.0160372141346218,0.0195823634945183,0.0194662853906029,0.210238966995079,0.214336846678592,0.0249594765054333,0.210238916319798,0.210174834609117,0.0160318994709102,0.214335071379163,0.206045960234447,0.0255020291948972,0.0191514070197920,0.214357602432308,0.206542702146590,0.214742975116791,0.0160372357356184,0.0148147075914217,0.214357387402113,0.0152429779057424,0.0255706181961383,0.0191533908273221,0.214743489863350,0.0253241612716207,0.210241970404247,0.210071601252672,0.0194817372415143,0.0147941927876125,0.0148018656755615,0.214757056403378,0.214757031728551,0.214335086888962,0.210238955632895,0.0198338587419603,0.214357584956370,0.0255530707500345,0.206046939317188,0.0160298996709891,0.0148073198801432,0.00568863125766442,0.214758222295078,0.0255017802844324,0.0160371191779804,0.208523430910316,0.00568905187843758,0.214758326371914,0.00575642738112647,0.0152774183425388,0.214335102727286,0.214757166042283,0.210173248841773,0.00567338708438994,0.214758325344603,0.0249850993961228,0.214757729184938,0.0191514021391454,0.00566581204157164,0.00566762463060673,0.214336845558277,0.214362322720576,0.214659174085802,0.214314396501528,0.0147979125811683,0.214757996545952,0.206046521999863,0.00569560076975685,0.0255019430778615,0.0194826887783724,0.208518802477297,0.214768759671368,0.0148149907737578,0.214659127715640,0.00566541154243674,0.210119513174995,0.00566720893503280,0.00574283093868470,0.214691722083512,0.0253245792453223,0.00562983424542308,0.0160300924815731,0.00566562473087818,0.197561953180131,0.214757988381898,0.214719245009013,0.00562982739294430,0.0198340318964857,0.210243548429197,0.206239866849448,0.214743451046238,0.0160373865987312,0.00568430979855541,0.00566514344372227,0.214354406419197,0.214644103770998,0.214768893334085,0.0255530977340453,0.00570213323245468,0.206073106107253,0.00562961194278866,0.00566562921143917,0.214719239222252,0.210071510523571,0.0191518393732263,0.214645546415560,0.214757967759513,0.0255018436968558,0.0147978803050905,0.00569970001652962,0.0910737198949864,0.00566523213448041,0.210237434682426,0.214647211717304,0.00564025793253943,0.00562961236664405,0.0249594838356594,0.0997966429613268,0.214743504686308,0.0148074716631733,0.214757831163465,0.214656454615578,0.00566528302226082,0.0194822342521198,0.214333623503738,0.00566562782305841,0.197550687945838,0.00562978564286574,0.214758589220931,0.0160298180952199,0.00566562662462339,0.206045972018849,0.00562764955398706,0.208519188662715,0.197618517783362,0.214757952433393,0.00567854951199238,0.210173711528825,0.00562958413743625,0.214743443508836,0.214656431944178,0.0837004291039642,0.0255018294931472,0.206239917679250,0.00566495927873979,0.00566544851483965,0.214719227813214,0.00569881236414012,0.0910732145290633,0.00566390829262771,0.206239934518351,0.214333679118859,0.0252518336817432,0.0160371887457630,0.0997487390221966,0.00562763034290696,0.0194820071771297,0.00566251853391868,0.214758604788082,0.0124601039308122,0.214656455292650,0.214645530206401,0.00566560859433952,0.101334029882552,0.206047019063713,0.00566433165563697,0.214757864572327,0.214414636865094,0.210119659691529,0.00564017098563218,0.0148073339164150,0.00566561923514171,0.00562763488483438,0.197550687879151,0.00569995987039952,0.214691753924120,0.0255272674834333,0.214323182381853,0.00566542921306101,0.00562923798400053,0.214768827848942,0.197561242050702,0.00566541706063338,0.214645529367941,0.0837073018581673,0.214656445914317,0.00569889653388857,0.0253241101452059,0.0910731956037563,0.0194828973667658,0.00566596670247434,0.0160372569759267,0.206196008150922,0.00562763397641850,0.214356178128416,0.0980338211112860,0.00562756323663910,0.210070699551954,0.214757870604343,0.214645554932188,0.206239904635974,0.00566233476861862,0.00566543711906521,0.00569022542318348,0.0148000578404910,0.0997515359652054,0.00562762619593274,0.214675474593720,0.206045881715940,0.210237369335844,0.00566539245493518,0.214767920211796,0.00566031930472949,0.00562759595450673,0.00569709152240730,0.101325497595788,0.214655558198088,0.0195773337880169,0.00566558485148925,0.0255012850414525,0.00563812665956213,0.00566362192981511,0.214355276125570,0.197537362200132,0.214756927338149,0.0160305664436211,0.0910709461123999,0.0837042844871378,0.00569667446534373,0.214644610958543,0.00562751419017800,0.00566558415894643,0.206218640348336,0.197560148350957,0.206239461940862,0.210117908346875,0.00563593385699497,0.0911233869160013,0.214766634468759,0.0118119783930223,0.00566538652467193,0.00566428018374553,0.214658118304302,0.00566054078796859,0.00562753894630160,0.0997489770541703,0.206046146308959,0.00566539820442181,0.214646315557630,0.0240117398815933,0.214333038810777,0.00566030333511086,0.214756975028930,0.00569723973049091,0.00562751148897249,0.101323761763062,0.0837238781736134,0.0160370967530527,0.00566522311670639,0.214644474669340,0.00562753497218323,0.00566030687166441,0.101331981770025,0.214766707722852,0.214657985696655,0.197546352140358,0.206237399536189,0.00566559683017596,0.00569681190405464,0.00569392472108486,0.0910709419256218,0.0255011506283987,0.00562752644225681,0.197561149797016,0.00566558939141339,0.210236890569246,0.00563797928791271,0.00562753563701984,0.0836975662780545,0.214755584345138,0.0911232057953077,0.214644648753686,0.00566272090509845,0.0995292277918181,0.00562751589474673,0.00562754235900959,0.0182299947866128,0.214755016691876,0.206239016970264,0.00566040664050630,0.208514550424491,0.00563591563257861,0.214654412079995,0.0997504825140557,0.00569711024981432,0.00566402469630571,0.0837054185873698,0.00568988292431222,0.101326656778311,0.206218632543177,0.00566027160682271,0.00562751427091694,0.197491101025519,0.214755592253942,0.197559342957378,0.00566530643726715,0.00566559300179330,0.214644638219273,0.0910709420656797,0.00569696244127481,0.00566516674136665,0.0240117978456929,0.00562735682738587,0.214360276061191,0.00566031300173997,0.00562751758657116,0.214654283569376,0.0911215844073050,0.0836982511909623,0.206239003482520,0.00569667020266130,0.0980298615379077,0.00562753994142118,0.00562751338757159,0.00568129816823584,0.214689446966901,0.197616070760572,0.0997501218818325,0.00566039750290055,0.214643260666082,0.210172159894641,0.101326081685347,0.197543653264159,0.00566029655715257,0.101332006875959,0.00562754292595353,0.00569777898821373,0.0837050650461753,0.00566532322317370,0.00566025000574584,0.00562750860036746,0.214643342456955,0.00562753892112040,0.00566369869393197,0.206195101102190,0.0910708951837069,0.00566553944468280,0.214653963143931,0.00569697129109573,0.00562751148936226,0.00563831671829865,0.0910709723020920,0.206235908716276,0.0836975967112618,0.0911305777446950,0.197546593439419,0.00566024981890347,0.00569666064632773,0.00562751119931685,0.0997477652318817,0.00562767964634049,0.101332010426829,0.101326663062012,0.00563799449322113,0.0997504482169451,0.00566048146843354,0.206210992673362,0.0912052733896331,0.00563591775497325,0.197553150186324,0.00562751048202212,0.0837052729736496,0.00562773601308180,0.00569767334841387,0.197547404561535,0.00562768383434014,0.00566025382533163,0.0910708925508483,0.101323640085139,0.00566042157740434,0.101332053193618,0.00569696585723999,0.00563591931552810,0.0910710793572147,0.0911240433251874,0.00566038355778010,0.00566025378247507,0.0997502092874987,0.0836981089609996,0.101326310911862,0.00569663441942209,0.101331978073613,0.0997670759161382,0.00563798694574664,0.00566033478044578,0.00566025642432739,0.0912080487621022,0.0837024653014371,0.0997659545201052,0.00566027876769984,0.00563833307246328,0.0837051359005938,0.00569777940936678,0.00566034037359204,0.0997897534006340,0.0911229197483921,0.0910682890415283,0.0910721809410106,0.00566024819876262,0.00569697537859936,0.00569662825334301,0.00569704937798394,0.0997501766396996,0.0912080490892067,0.00566034732749028,0.0995287511749117,0.0836980583966294,0.0995305194237347,0.00566025067056789,0.00566245823307448,0.00566035245720320,0.00566046370374880,0.0910710025701171,0.0837044240668410,0.0910711207842465,0.0837051121580313,0.00569711716178703,0.00569661387677411,0.0912080338363357,0.00569702870694769,0.0910708939306970,0.00566036013677245,0.0911215824826311,0.00569710126341917,0.0911241458097106,0.00566300750673699,0.0836975314479976,0.00566266989374762,0.0910708490978527,0.00569664994937451,0.0837045077659306,0.0910721088862271,0.00569690471476277,0.00569762570246854,0.0837050109539635,0.0910721691399745,0.00569662266869397,0.0910709623587325,0.00569673511800935,0.00569720903059033,0.0837047120555439,0.00569691480085519,0.0836979988297883,0.0837063970989298,0.00569711535952094,0.0837064141597426,0.00569697268268150,0.00569736183262831,0.0836880736710230;0.0402615177262752,0.0402646114951072,0.0402613980037733,0.0402649255820213,0.0404037763179536,0.0402623956468885,0.0402615726058088,0.0402624722329828,0.0403109608851254,0.0410230262140974,0.0403869509660742,0.0402644842898950,0.0403102980009575,0.0403213513009565,0.0410201035268354,0.0418263180917558,0.0402613547689623,0.0402645986665898,0.0418690657574100,0.0403859904626285,0.0402614849380958,0.0427446252883425,0.0427444720041864,0.0403008704805611,0.0408019050004555,0.0419304645117564,0.0417928841454516,0.0403104394269801,0.0427459954990650,0.0418692329041598,0.0417929153593718,0.0402614046872008,0.0402624525512568,0.0427935322354578,0.0419387316196163,0.0419623951251880,0.0441945874567450,0.0481785036446434,0.0402645477234609,0.0402644599623248,0.0410181364448346,0.0402681603058012,0.0435406559696383,0.0449615698023685,0.0427421833704801,0.0428025901707676,0.0419308392451515,0.0481827659570628,0.0404405367350053,0.0419305429576457,0.0418690231435140,0.0449665733359871,0.0481781048075747,0.0402613944901389,0.0402644249530883,0.0429798845703107,0.0482395912167198,0.0403869992767753,0.0503758811888232,0.0449614914071162,0.0459227607340810,0.0482388527611891,0.0455716986264869,0.0402629080862847,0.0429795934522993,0.0503789842149941,0.0403103379530633,0.0419347980618202,0.0417928013039721,0.0427935278579730,0.0459411709294789,0.0459352666348599,0.0505571884289661,0.0505165073922008,0.0481781406516024,0.0419305367034199,0.0426275163350987,0.0482395509421753,0.0402613307964892,0.0402614149199718,0.0449668777316082,0.0459290596732144,0.0549145102225215,0.385739397708640,0.0402644786802928,0.0449615599009715,0.0410199741491655,0.0549117068347235,0.385739252021593,0.0548443153066804,0.0455465761723380,0.0481790276727869,0.0505190425751970,0.0418690260248455,0.0549324054501877,0.385739352848804,0.0404309659571442,0.385742941092387,0.0429798897953262,0.0549379131100567,0.0549376983112668,0.0481824427031117,0.0482615931629000,0.386059305336253,0.0481441661637009,0.0459374388846971,0.385741375475807,0.0402613412770053,0.0549051447381979,0.0402644758361392,0.0427928968416163,0.0410180375782228,0.0509628518969319,0.0459225251028307,0.386059723556527,0.0549383022436148,0.0418262543493062,0.0549380063683340,0.515692527956016,0.385964622288168,0.0403101944976781,0.0550285128015616,0.0449667123710021,0.0549380768328730,0.410889817363875,0.385742086899769,0.385875865701474,0.0550284346880272,0.0426273722469247,0.0419381658110320,0.399635435307890,0.0503787765037235,0.0449613862465492,0.0549172631069264,0.0549386875830318,0.0482297789862493,0.386091474742902,0.385485996007775,0.0402613175632778,0.0548986103137835,0.0402671763174666,0.0550275605385031,0.0549380758096837,0.385875929668546,0.0417927931470956,0.0429794678565275,0.386089129048662,0.385742092543341,0.0402644578120081,0.0459374706993373,0.515698907046057,0.513750680062174,0.0549385988038424,0.0419303472706256,0.386085872308710,0.515562964887681,0.0550276474465500,0.0404405156177829,0.508391496762690,0.0503798374985946,0.0459289353445535,0.385742963358070,0.386066458089412,0.0549385505066583,0.0427930659344674,0.0481781291911576,0.0549380807862313,0.410902707217838,0.0550676526471277,0.385734652029444,0.0449669227025252,0.0549380813682479,0.0402613096007258,0.0550277618583968,0.0410181487204433,0.410820341165047,0.385742366729363,0.0549230273097717,0.0418691891921973,0.0550286932940511,0.0503795127464803,0.386066448865716,0.515699128322005,0.0402644603058369,0.399635489398018,0.515672342126691,0.0549383750091405,0.385875940035903,0.0549019326982389,0.513751135963299,0.0549415579754186,0.399635397113438,0.0481780765668797,0.0403348862441939,0.0449614942125149,0.508430429655408,0.0550278505913396,0.0427932563711380,0.515669926743614,0.385735097571052,0.0481684563413332,0.386066391545351,0.386089156129770,0.0549381004824841,0.507119090169805,0.0402614218040705,0.0549406156394356,0.385742863929403,0.0485325540986764,0.0418263800384668,0.515564279952887,0.0459290541590138,0.0549380862025039,0.0550277717257324,0.410902715495432,0.515699047921659,0.385964572009837,0.0402623634080227,0.0481606145467929,0.0549382784055612,0.515138160174222,0.385486685184380,0.410890899739035,0.0549384052789182,0.386089173851786,0.515698249686228,0.386066416094720,0.515698964259594,0.0403103319949233,0.513751194054555,0.0427927255312670,0.0549377345467470,0.0449613978312116,0.399694494372811,0.0550277607935996,0.0482400691967642,0.509531264151258,0.0550279303594017,0.0417919280159848,0.385742778949100,0.386089168307745,0.399635443374842,0.515670294758875,0.0549383859606190,0.0549105223297036,0.0459354709738370,0.508428474569812,0.0550277673105449,0.386013294100139,0.0402618217897069,0.0419305551964017,0.0549386971766082,0.385483331715437,0.515671054220630,0.0550322145881771,0.515700233264551,0.507126480647128,0.386067386774471,0.0427448542434159,0.0549383835333207,0.0402652142130110,0.515564668984354,0.0549421199964330,0.0482430130370852,0.410916050763712,0.385743851176073,0.0449665617556750,0.513752303713092,0.515699352729428,0.515700091872683,0.386090136655131,0.0550282201523826,0.0549383842645738,0.399664347129697,0.410892081209054,0.399635891176550,0.0418270865885791,0.515536905615815,0.513727183229228,0.385483108437399,0.0487910863074164,0.0549385952065463,0.0549409235645345,0.386060623555355,0.515671198981422,0.0550281353061298,0.508429819156218,0.0402623067254086,0.0549387090828968,0.386086880413909,0.0408023229336468,0.0481827737199096,0.515671047203127,0.385743831242300,0.515700227106684,0.0550323119082496,0.507128030121708,0.515694935942368,0.0449618913940363,0.0549388713303223,0.386090283258660,0.0550281341250099,0.515671047202252,0.507121526937193,0.0510076368991850,0.386061320065022,0.410906905879797,0.399638552161280,0.0549383812160748,0.515700104047715,0.0549070814502990,0.513752298411520,0.0402653562690286,0.0550322388914790,0.410890978513073,0.0549383791634935,0.0419310735849066,0.515564041652515,0.0550281305384516,0.515700229964891,0.385743727373710,0.513727285722351,0.386090122038246,0.515673417097924,0.508576402219843,0.0550322744188893,0.0550281729969058,0.0435497680987762,0.0505675397335884,0.399636402606436,0.515671204589365,0.0410178803377484,0.515537107058431,0.386067431824490,0.508429585348627,0.515700229477950,0.0549411918278402,0.515699274142077,0.0549111298046456,0.507126531777182,0.399664369311817,0.515671047557268,0.0550282199989704,0.410962388400867,0.385743745693510,0.410893032141858,0.0549388137877190,0.0549383793558447,0.386090137041650,0.513752301778687,0.515700229259562,0.0549389319061940,0.0408023117218113,0.515142176446968,0.0482657235544087,0.515670881045487,0.0550282052475321,0.386067460697682,0.513728063856807,0.515700229366248,0.399636444854491,0.515700105426924,0.509533495385650,0.0550281240229302,0.0550323338442967,0.0549205501423682,0.385965440637612,0.410823434447545,0.508429805622918,0.515671208248685,0.386092392148680,0.0418740049291331,0.507127010922834,0.410909646546145,0.515670846107566,0.507121483446919,0.0550281215140493,0.515700229103109,0.515699323482930,0.0549387729172596,0.515670954097647,0.0550322968952822,0.386090037445153,0.0550281285793550,0.0549420397200549,0.399695593285342,0.513752318345951,0.0549425232028789,0.386067484676202,0.515700229256287,0.0550322865533737,0.515566221629113,0.513752288230385,0.399639026625040,0.515700228763018,0.513722977802497,0.410906686395280,0.515670953916228,0.515700091440013,0.0550322911048119,0.508431515564294,0.0550321146383236,0.507121464399041,0.507126519699439,0.515564046432906,0.508429602553560,0.515671208049054,0.399670664913279,0.513678485752142,0.515541451058038,0.410899220689911,0.0550322924434519,0.515699324656803,0.0550320714927994,0.515700229021870,0.410903564270673,0.0550321211492873,0.515670964993704,0.513752320243256,0.507127879724927,0.515670890541561,0.507121456788515,0.515700226368377,0.515541460201994,0.513752288068557,0.513727397703908,0.515671121660423,0.515670960984248,0.508429808117694,0.515700230443423,0.507126819477801,0.515700094462283,0.507121529566563,0.508416531483016,0.515563958559148,0.515670810928860,0.515670925767318,0.513678538807481,0.515699206868589,0.508416455507559,0.515670819337278,0.515566172678542,0.515699351757915,0.515700233629785,0.515671103798426,0.508398543242159,0.513727256245349,0.513753164939830,0.513752278814650,0.515670876988801,0.515700228871978,0.515700102426958,0.515700098927955,0.508429796928896,0.513678541104408,0.515671114530635,0.508577422833552,0.515700234069954,0.508576250815707,0.515670919333874,0.515673098038652,0.515671111810140,0.515671080060946,0.513752286206687,0.515699250968339,0.513752135665734,0.515699355969864,0.515700229077286,0.515700007732135,0.513678508170534,0.515700226060707,0.513752321181964,0.515671123652810,0.513728064853236,0.515700120438933,0.513727387154900,0.515673619713699,0.515700229465978,0.515673330739241,0.513752212447033,0.515699987190417,0.515699255122203,0.513752300234572,0.515700141975395,0.515700202795628,0.515699324835162,0.513752301042668,0.515700007616421,0.513752301373972,0.515700027406645,0.515700138686779,0.515699235366129,0.515700157614684,0.515700225872017,0.515699319196249,0.515700218936329,0.515699285226254,0.515700115240635,0.515700145151232,0.515700229736198];
```

Comment: So, all of your 500 points lie on that surface (2-simplex), and you wan to connect them. I suspect there are more constrains that you need to add, e.g. `A` is convex. Otherwise there will be loads of possibilities and not a clear way of tying the points. Can you write a bit more on how you define `A`?

Comment: @AnderBiguri Thanks. Your comment should be related to when in my code I do 
`A = convexHull(T)`. Is this what you are asking?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not very far! Just few style options and the plot of the 2-simplex and you should be good to go! Remove edges of your `patch` (so it looks flat) and make another `patch` call using the 3 corners of the 2-simplex. Nothing more needed.

```
T = delaunayTriangulation(R.');
A = convexHull(T);


% plot 2-simplex
patch([0 0 1],[0 1 0],[1 0 0],[0.8 0.8 0.8]);
axis equal 
axis([0 1 0 1 0 1])
view(120,30)

hold on

%plot A

patch('Faces',A,'Vertices',T.Points,'FaceColor','k','edgecolor','none');
```

[image]

```
% optional: plot the points
plot3(R(1,:).',R(2,:).',R(3,:).','r.');
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks, amazing! I put a +1 but it doesn't show because I don't have enough reputation.

Comment: @TEX no worries ;) Keep asking nice questions like this and you will have enough reputation soon!